# Ajax not working for many form on same page

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

in a view im repating the same form and posting it via ajax, my concern is the ajax is working for 1st form but not working from second form, below is the code im using.

```
<form action="http://localhost/comment" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="comment_text" value="" id="comment_text" size="35" class="comment_text">
<input type="submit" id="post_comment" name="post_comment" value="submit comment" class="post_comment" >
</form>
<form action="http://localhost/comment" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="comment_text" value="" id="comment_text" size="35" class="comment_text">
<input type="submit" id="post_comment" name="post_comment" value="submit comment" class="post_comment" >
</form>
<form action="http://localhost/comment" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="comment_text" value="" id="comment_text" size="35" class="comment_text">
<input type="submit" id="post_comment" name="post_comment" value="submit comment" class="post_comment" >
</form>
<form action="http://localhost/comment" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="comment_text" value="" id="comment_text" size="35" class="comment_text">
<input type="submit" id="post_comment" name="post_comment" value="submit comment" class="post_comment" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.post_comment').click(function() {
  var form_data = {
    csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
    post_text: $('.comment_text').val()    
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('/comment'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response){
      $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique. You can, however, apply a class to more than one element. Change `id="post_comment"` to `class="post_comment"`.

Comment: he's using classes as-well. The id's are invalid, but that shouldn't affect the code since he isn't using them. I suspect a delegation issue, along with he's always getting the value from the first form rather than the form that is being submitted.

Comment: @Kevin B True, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `post_text: $('.comment_text', this).val()` which will give you the value of the first selected `.comment`, what you want is the `.comment` in the current form. Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.post_comment').click(function() {
  var form_data = {
    csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
    post_text: $(this).closest('form').find('.comment_text').val()    
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('/comment'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response){
      $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Also element ids should be unique.